# why Response.Redirect keep load current page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Home.aspx", false);
}
```

Why my page keep load on default.aspx and not redirect to Home.aspx,After load finish my browser will pop up an error "The page isn't redirecting properly" tell me to clear the cookie but I follow still the same?

Comment: try that Response.Redirect("Home.aspx", true);

Comment: true also samesame error

Comment: Try giving redirection in session start or try enabling cookies  thanks

Answer (score 0):

please visit the following [Link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903)

**Extract from above link**

The HttpResponse class implements two overloaded versions of the Redirect method.
The first overloaded method takes only one input parameter, which is the URL for the target location. This version is defined as follows:

```
public void Redirect(string url);
```

The second overloaded method takes two input parameters: the URL for the target location, and a boolean value that indicates whether to stop running the current page. This version is defined as follows:

```
public void Redirect(string url, bool endResponse);
```

When you use the first overloaded version, the second overloaded version is called internally and is passed a boolean value of True for the second input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">
  protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
  {
      Response.Redirect("Home.aspx");
      base.OnLoad(e);
  }
</script>
```